# Twitter Bootstrap tooltip on dynamicly added elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Are tooltips (popovers) supposed to work on newly added elements?

If they are just inserted in dome with jquery:

link

It does not work for me only after I attach $('a').tooltip() plugin  manually.

Comment: Do you mean, even after calling `$('a').tooltip()` it didn't work?

Comment: It works, I thought that it should work without it, just because of right markup as it works for other bootstrap things (for example tabs - I dont need to attache any plugins to make it work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should call `.tooltip()`" to initialize it, especially if you are dynamically inserting a new element. This is also the case for most of the plugins.

Otherwise you would have to implement a listener to check if any element that requires tooltips are added (i.e. via `setTimeout`, etc); which wouldn't be so efficient.

On the other hand; some plugin features might not fully depend on Javascript triggers. The CSS-only controls will always pick it up when a new element is created and has the referenced CSS class or id in the style sheet.

Comment: I just wonder why tabs are working without calling tabs()? Do you know the difference?

Comment: Ok, then tabs might be CSS-only. Class names, etc might be parsed via JS but if the functionality depends only on CSS, it works. But tooltips are more complicated and they require real-time information such as cursor/element location, dynamic text (tip), etc..